# How filter function works when using object instead of a callback function?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to filter out empty values and am success using `.filter(String)`:

```
['foo','bar','',''].filter(String);
// ['foo','bar']
```

It was my desired result and worked as expected.

But suddenly looking it a deeper:

```
'' instanceof String // false
'foo' instanceof String // false
''.constructor.prototype // String.prototype
'foo'.constructor.prototype // String.prototype
```

So, we can't see any difference. And surprised how is this actually working. Looking at the above conditions, it should just return `['foo','bar','','']` as is because all string values.

## Edit:

I deleted my answer, just because, I think it's not fully satisfies:

Filter function satisfies the Boolean value at the end.

```
Boolean('') // false, so remove
Boolean('foo') // true, so keep it
```

String is a constructor - a function as pointed out by @Nina Scholz in the comment.

Well, it is not a constructor - pointed out by @Bergi. Agreed. But now fully surprised how `.filter(String)` will be `.filter(s=>String(s))` - because String is not a function call at all.

Comment: where is actually the question?

Comment: See the title....

Comment: but `String` is a constructor, a function.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah, thanks. I was getting it in wrong point of veiw (just thought of Object reference)

Comment: Are you [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or figured out the answer once you posted the question?. Because the question and answer are unclear at the moment

Comment: At first, I was not able to know, how was it working, but when posting, I got idea and posted as an answer. Ah, sorry if it is unclear. I will delete then. (Just posted if someone else in future might have same question) - should I delete this or keep? Because I might only be a foolish at the moment...

Comment: Please make it a valid Q & A. I don't know how "Damn! It satisfies the Boolean value" supposed to answer this question

Comment: ah, okay. thanks for your guideline.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if you're actually trolling

Comment: @adiga No. Not at all. It happens sometimes to me. Don't know why. I don't understand even small things often.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to with being `instanceof String`.

```
['foo','bar','',''].filter(String);
```

is same as

```
['foo','bar','',''].filter(a => String(a));
```

`String('')` returns an empty string `''`. And this is **[`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)** value. So, those gets [filtered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out because:

> `filter()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback **returns a value that coerces to true**

So, if you were to have a `0` (number) in the array, it wouldn't get filtered even though `0 instance of String === false`. Because `String(0)` returns `"0"` which is `truthy` value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use different contructors, like [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/), [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/), [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) or [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/), for example. The callback returns different values, like

- `Boolean` returns only [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values,
- `String` returns all values, except empty strings `''`, arrays with a single empty string `['']` and empty arrays `[]`,
- `Array`, `Object` returns returns all,
- `Number` returns only truthy values after converting to number.

```js
var array = [-1, 0, 1, NaN, Infinity, '', 'a', 'b', true, false, undefined, null, {}, { a: 1 }, [], [''], [1], [1, 2]];

console.log(array.filter(Boolean));
console.log(array.filter(String));
console.log(array.filter(Array));
console.log(array.filter(Object));
console.log(array.filter(Number));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You forgot to actually test the empty string :-) `Array` and `Object` always return an object which is never falsy

Comment: In fact, with this answer. I am a little confused as I was previously.